# Prove uniqueness via a connectedness argument

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, connectedness

I am reading an article about uniqueness of some evolution PDE and at some point, the author says that to show uniqueness on an interval $[0,T]$, by a "classical connectedness argument" (his words) it was enough to show it on a time interval $[0,T'] \subset [0,T]$, for $T'$ arbitrarily small. I am not sure to understand what he means by this.

I thought maybe consider $\{t~|~u_1(t) = u_2(t)\}$, for $u_1, u_2$ two solutions, which is a closed set and then try to show it is open as well so that this gives us uniqueness by connectedness. However I do not see exactly how to do it with the uniqueness on $[0,T']$ arbitrarily small. Does anyone know how to do that ?

Comment: Let $a=\max\{S:u_1=u_2\text{ on }[0,S]\}$.  If $a<T$, you get a contradiction by running the argument starting at $a$.

Comment: I am sorry, could you be a bit more precise? I do not see where is the contradiction.

Comment: Translating everything so that $a$ becomes zero, that is, applying the change of variables $s=t-a$, the statement regarding the small $T'$ would imply that $u_1=u_2$ on $[a,a+T']$ contradicting the fact that $a$ is the maximum.